# Remove \r from a javascript property and value

Tags: javascript, properties

After I do a csv-upload and parse it I get this kind of object:

```
var obj = {
    "section": "KM1+000",
    "velocity\r": "100\r"
}

console.log(obj.section); //KM1+000
console.log(obj.velocity); //undefined
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zxrk9qx4/

For some reason a \r is added to the last property. This result in I cant access it properly. Is there anyway I can remove \r from my object?

Comment: I think must be "velocity\\r" in your example. Cause '\r' will become just 'r' in javascript;

Comment: @alexpods Not it won't, just like most languages, \r is the escape for a CR. Try it.

Comment: @JuanMendes Ooh yeah, sorry)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access it using `obj['velocity\r']`

If you want to strip any `\r`s from all the keys, you can do this.

```js
    var old = {
      "section": "KM1+000",
      "velocity\r": "100\r"
    };

    function stripCRFromKeys(obj) {
      var newObj = {};
      for (var key in obj) {
        newObj[key.replace(/\r/g, '')] = obj[key];
      }
      return newObj;
    }
    console.log(old["velocity\r"]);
    var obj = stripCRFromKeys(old);
    console.log(obj.velocity)
```

Notice that you should really try to fix whoever is generating that object if you can